# How to get input from user in function

Tags: matlab

I want to ask about function M-file in MATLAB: if I want input from the user, how do I do that?

Can I write the input directly in the function M-file?

Or do I have to write an input statement in a script file and return to the function file to write another statement?

Comment: Have you checked the `input` function? That might be what you want. Type `help input` to see how it works

Answer (score 2):

As Luis mentioned, the `input` function ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html)) prompts the user and then receives input.  As far as I know, it will work fine whether in a function or in a script.  If you find that it doesn't, post the code so folks can take a look at it.

`input` will treat what the user types as if you had typed it at a matlab command line.  For example, if your code says

```
count=input('Enter a count')
```

and the user enters `3*5`, the value of `count` will be `15`.  To get exactly "3*5", use `input('Prompt','s')` instead.